# Riak yokozuna (solr) search stopped working after join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, riak

Are there additional steps you need to take after joining new Riak nodes to a cluster to set up  yokozuna/solr?

Solr was working on one node. When I joined two additional nodes solr seems to have stopped. Solr is not running any of the nodes, including on the original node that was working before the cluster was created.

**Update:** I had the original node leave the cluster and restarted it to test it on it's own. It is still throwing the same error.

**Update: contents of log/riak/solr.log**

2014-11-05 19:34:13,581 [WARN] @CoreAdminHandler.java:495 Creating a core with existing name is not allowed
2014-11-05 19:34:13,582 [ERROR] @SolrException.java:109 org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Core with name 'normalized_people' already exists.
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:496)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:152)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.handleAdminRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:732)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2014-11-05 19:34:13,582 [ERROR] @SolrException.java:120 null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Core with name 'normalized_people' already exists.
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleCreateAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:496)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:152)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.handleAdminRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:732)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

No additional steps are necessary. Please check the log files, especially `/var/log/riak/solr.log` for clues as to what the error could be.

Based on your description, reproduction steps should be:

- Start one Riak node with search enabled and create a search index (`normalized_people`)
- Start other Riak nodes with search enabled and join to cluster
- Check for error

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it has something to do with indexes already existing? After the normalized errors I get Server refused connection and time out errors, but I'm assuming that's because solr isn't starting.